# cannot be resolved to a variable - gui controller code

Tags: java, swing

Ok - I have the following code - on the starred part I get errors.  The ItemManager class requires that I fill the () with Items.  However when I do I get the error that Items cannot be resolved to a variable and I am unsure of how to fix that.

```
package presentation;
import javax.swing.*;

import business.ItemManager;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import business.*;

public class CreateInventoryUI extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3940805393905465307L;
    private JButton addBtn = new JButton ("Add Item to Inventory");
    private JButton showBtn = new JButton ("Display Inventory");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CreateInventoryUI frame = new CreateInventoryUI("Inventory");
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Exception - Sorry");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public CreateInventoryUI(String name) { // title bar name
        super(name);

        // layout here
        Container container = getContentPane();
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(new JButton("Display inventory"));
        container.add(new JButton("Add Item to Inventory"));


        addBtn.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                // controller code
                ***ItemManager mngr = new ItemManager();
                mngr.store(Items);***
            }
        });



        showBtn.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                // controller code
                ItemManager mngr = new ItemManager();
                mngr.get(Items);
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }


    /**
     * Constructs a <code>String</code> with all attributes
     * in name = value format.
     *
     * @return a <code>String</code> representation 
     * of this object.
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        final String TAB = "    ";

        String retValue = "";

        retValue = "CreateInventoryUI ( "
            + super.toString() + TAB
            + "addBtn = " + this.addBtn + TAB
            + "showBtn = " + this.showBtn + TAB
            + " )";

        return retValue;
    }


}
```

Comment: The `()` is known as parameter. Please mark as homework to get better answers.

Comment: Can you post the compiler error, and any previous errors in the same ouptput?  I wonder if this is a cascading error...

Comment: You are passing a class instead of an instance of `Items`. Which library are you using? Do you have javadocs for it?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `Items` to `mngr.store` but you do not have `Items` declared anywhere. [Also, by convention class names begin with a capital and variables begin with a lowercase, so you probably want the variable to be named `items`, which is of type `Items`]

Answer (score 0):

`Items` is not defined anywhere in your code sample.

Furthermore, you probably want to add these buttons:

```
container.add(addBtn);
container.add(showBtn);
```

in your `CreateInventoryUI` method, not creating new instances for `container.add()`.